# Retrieving Subscriptions IAP Product List Using Flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I am implementing auto renewable subscriptions in [Flutter](https://flutter.dev). I have successfully implemented them for Android using this package `https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase`. However, it is not working on iOS.

I have followed all of the instructions to create the auto renewable subscription in app center, but when I try to fetch the list of products in the app it returns `null`. Please help me to resolve this issue I am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a product configuration issue in App Store Connect or you're not testing on a physical device. Common things to check:

1. You're using a physical device (iOS simulators don't like StoreKit APIs)
2. Your products in App Store Connect are in the 'Ready To Submit' state (don't forget to include the screenshots)
3. You've signed your 'Paid Applications Agreement' in App Store Connect (this is required even for testing)

This blog post covers these cases and more in a bit more detail: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, I am testing on the real device, 3rd point is the only missing thing from my end. I'll get back to you soon. Once again thanks for your response :)

Comment: Thankyou very much I was just missing the 3rd point, After doing that IAP works perfectly. God bless you :)